# What does the |= operator do in Java?

Tags: java, operators

While reading the [Android guide to Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html), I stumbled across this:

> **Adding vibration**
>
> You can alert the user with the the default vibration pattern or with a
>   vibration pattern defined by your application.
>
> To use the default pattern, add "DEFAULT_VIBRATE" to the defaults field:
>
> ```
> notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
> ```

What this does is clear: it adds the `DEFAULT_VIBRATE` flag to the default flags of the notification object.
But what does the `|=` operator do in Java? 
It looks like an "OR", but how does it work?

Can you provide an example using numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`|=` is a bitwise-OR-assignment operator. It takes the current value of the LHS, bitwise-ors the RHS, and assigns the value back to the LHS (in a similar fashion to `+=` does with addition).

For example:

```
foo = 32;   // 32 =      0b00100000
bar = 9;    //  9 =      0b00001001
baz = 10;   // 10 =      0b00001010
foo |= bar; // 32 | 9  = 0b00101001 = 41
            // now foo = 41
foo |= baz; // 41 | 10 = 0b00101011 = 43
            // now foo = 43
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that it can be used with two boolean arguments - as with the other bitwise operators. The difference between this and the normal `||` / `&&` operators is that they will not evaluate the second operand unless needed.

Answer (score 20):

`a |= x` is `a = a | x`, and `|` is "bitwise inclusive OR"

Whenever such questions arise, check [the official tutorial on operators](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Each operator has an assignment form:

`+=` `-=` `*=` `/=` `%=` `&=` `^=` `|=` `<<=` `>>=` `>>>=`

Where `a OP= x` is translated to `a = a OP x`

And about [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation):

```
   0101 (decimal 5)
OR 0011 (decimal 3)
 = 0111 (decimal 7)
```

> The bitwise OR may be used in situations where a set of bits are used as flags; the bits in a single binary numeral may each represent a distinct Boolean variable. Applying the bitwise OR operation to the numeral along with a bit pattern containing 1 in some positions will result in a new numeral with those bits set.

Comment: That's what I did, but I could not find the |= form, that looks strange to me

Comment: @bodom_lx well, it is there right there on the page I linked.

Comment: it is not..There is the bitwise-inclusive or operator "|", which I know. 
What I did not know was the "|=" form. 
I saw it today for the first time in my life and it did not looked obvious for me and my computer science class mates

Comment: 1. open the page. 2 press CTRL+F in your browser 3. type |= 4. see, it's there. 5. it's under "assignment" and there is "assignment" in the menu on the left.

Answer (score 5):

It is a short hand notation for performing a bitwise OR and an assignment in one step.

`x |= y` is equivalent to `x = x | y`

This can be done with many operators, for example:

```
x += y
x -= y
x /= y
x *= y
etc.
```

An example of the bitwise OR using numbers.. if either bit is set in the operands the bit will be set in the result. So, if:

```
x = 0001 and
y = 1100 then
--------
r = 1101
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `notification.defaults` is a [bit array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array).  By using `|=`, you're adding `Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE` to the set of default options.  Inside `Notification`, it is likely that the presence of this particular value will be checked for like so:

```
notification.defaults & Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE != 0 // Present
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the bit wise OR operator. If notifications.default is 0b00000001 in binary form and Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE is 0b11000000, then the result will be 0b11000001.

Answer (score 0):

bitwise OR operator

Comment: it is not _only_ the bitwise OR