# Interesting boolean syntax

Tags: java, boolean

I've lately bumped in something weird. Consider the following method:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<T> col) {
    boolean added = false;

    for(T t : col)
        added |= add(t);

    return added;
}
```

Although I understand what this wants to do, that's - not change it to false, if it exceeded at least once (if a later element failed). But what does this actually mean. How is it read. And are there any similar gadgets in `boolean`?

Comment: Don't you mean `|=`? I'm not sure your `=|` is valid syntax.

Comment: `added` is true if at least one item was successfully added.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325349/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java. Next time try SymbolHound: http://symbolhound.com/?q=java+%7C%3D+tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bitwise-or combined with an equals.

As such, if it has been set to true (i.e. `1`) before, if you bitwise or either a true or false (`1` or `0`) with it, you'll always return true (`1`) as `0 OR 1 = 1` and `1 OR 1 = 1`.

It is in effect the same as:

```
added = (added | add(t));
```

Comment: @MouseEvent: Not sure if that's valid, but even if it is, `||` is lazy-evaluated which means that if the left value is already true, then the `add()` function won't be called

Comment: That is a logical OR, which behaves differently to a bitwise OR. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014535/differences-in-boolean-operators-vs-and-vs

Comment: @Mark: Indeed it is lazily evaluated, the logical OR will short circuit whereas the bitwise OR will not.

Comment: @MouseEvent `||=` is not a valid operator.

Comment: I knew about bitwise operators, but never knew that booleans works this way too...

Comment: In Java, there is no special relationship between `true` and `1`

Comment: I was merely utilizing the effective similarity between `1` and `0` and `true` and `false`, since we're talking bitwise here I felt it would help with the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The `|=` operator is equivalent to this:

```
added = ( added | add(t) );
```